# spawn ENOENT error with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I get an error using GM() on my remote server, I think i get an issue when I try to write the file... It works perfectly on my local server...

My code :

```
gm()
.in('-page', '+0+0')
.in('/var/www/myapp/public/images/instabox.jpg')
.in('-page', '+10+10')
.in(image)
.mosaic()
.minify()
.write(newFileName, function (err) { // newfilename = '/var/www/myapp/public/uploads/mydir/image.jpg'
  if (!err) console.log('done');
  if (err) console.log(err);
  callback();
});
```

My error :

```
{ [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' }
```

**Response of the issue:**

> I put back GM on my remote server and it was the issue, GM was not
>   well installed...

Comment: check if your app has `read/write` permission over that area... or run your app with `sudo`

Comment: Check that graphicsmagick is installed on the remote server. Are you able to execute `gm` on the remote server via a terminal?

Comment: I put back GM on my remote server and it was the issue, GM was not well installed...

Comment: Put that as a answer, @tonymx227